# Android studio junit does not exist

Tags: java, android, junit

The other solutions to this issue did not work for me.

I get the error: "package org.junit does not exist" while running a simple Android Studio App example.   I downloaded the junit jar file but do not know how to add this to the classpath.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fortuneball"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            java.excludes = ['androidTest/**']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0' //Add this dependency
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar' //Add this dependency
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar' //Add this dependency
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit-dep', version: '4.10'

}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fortune_description"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/description_text_size"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fortunateImage"
        android:src="@drawable/img_crystal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fortuneText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/fortunateImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fortune_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fortuneButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/fortuneText"
        android:text="What's my fortune?"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>





package com.example.fortuneball;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just remove your last dependency

Comment: I did and I still get the error.